# LNK1104 error in Visual C++ 2010

Tags: visual-c++, linker-errors

I keep getting this comiler error. Compiling was working and then just suddenly stopped and is giving me this error and warning:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppClean.targets(74,5): warning : Access to the path 'C:\Users\Mohammad\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\CS HR\Debug\CS HR.exe' is denied.


LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\Users\Mohammad\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\CS HR\Debug\CS HR.exe'
```

Clearly the access denial is causing the compiler to be unable to open the file but I don't know why it access is being denied.

Comment: I am having the same problem and it is not due to the process already running. Win7 x64 with UAC enabled.

Comment: I have the same problem. When I close VS and re-open it, it's ok.

Answer (score 3):

The `CS HR.exe` process is still running, so the executable file cannot be overwritten by the linker.

Try using Task Manager to locate the running process and kill it, then build your project again.

Comment: anyway to prevent this from happening so I dont have to go to task manager everytime I compile and end the process?

Comment: @moesef, well, your program should terminate once its task is done. Is it some kind of service that is supposed to keep running forever?

Comment: it is not. but the problem is happening alot less frequently now so not a big deal anymore.

Comment: @moesef If your application is randomly not closing when you're finished, then you have a serious bug on your hands. You need to track down what's causing that first, before doing anything else. Occasional trouble compiling/linking will not be the only symptom of this bug.

Comment: i think it is being caused by infinite recursion. as i'm editing my code sometimes i accidentally make these infinite loops. this could cause the program to not close correctly as it is never truly finished. would you agree that this is probably the problem that i had?

Answer (score 0):

I think the process of exe is running,So first close the process and then try to link it.